# Shaded violin plot by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, violin-plot

I'm trying to produce a variation of a grouped violin plot in R (preferably using `ggplot2`), similar to the one below:

[image: Grouped Violin Plot]

which was produced by the following reproducible example code:

```
# Load libraries #
library(tidyverse)

# Create dummy data #
set.seed(321)
df <- data.frame(X = rep(c("X1", "X2"), each = 100), 
                 Y = rgamma(n = 200, shape = 2, rate = 2),
                 Z = rep(c("Za", "Zb"), rep = 100),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Grouped violin plot #
df %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = Z)) + 
    geom_violin(draw_quantiles = 0.5) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Za" = "red", "Zb" = "blue"))
```

The variation I'd like to have is that **the density above the median should have a different shade compared to the density below the median**, as in the following plot:

[image: Shaded Violin Plot]

I produced the above (single) violin plot for the combination `X = X1` and `Z = Za` in the data, using the following code:

```
## Shaded violin plot ##
# Calculate limits and median #
df.lim <- df %>% 
            filter(X == "X1", Z == "Za") %>% 
            summarise(Y_min = min(Y),
                      Y_qnt = quantile(Y, 0.5),
                      Y_max = max(Y))

# Calculate density, truncate at limits and assign shade category #
df.dens <- df %>% 
            filter(X == "X1", Z == "Za") %>% 
            do(data.frame(LOC  = density(.$Y)$x,
                          DENS = density(.$Y)$y)) %>%
            filter(LOC >= df.lim$Y_min, LOC <= df.lim$Y_max) %>% 
            mutate(COL = ifelse(LOC > df.lim$Y_qnt, "Empty", "Filled"))

# Find density values at limits #
df.lim.2 <- df.dens %>% 
              filter(LOC == min(LOC) | LOC == max(LOC))

# Produce shaded single violin plot #
df.dens %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = LOC)) + 
    geom_area(aes(y =  DENS, alpha = COL), fill = "red") +
    geom_area(aes(y = -DENS, alpha = COL), fill = "red") +
    geom_path(aes(y =  DENS)) +
    geom_path(aes(y = -DENS)) +
    geom_segment(data = df.lim.2, aes(x = LOC, y = DENS, xend = LOC, yend = -DENS)) +
    coord_flip() + 
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c("Empty" = 0.1, "Filled" = 1))
```

As you will notice in the code, I'm building the violin plot from scratch using the `density` function horizontally and then flipping the axes. The problem arises when I try to produce a grouped violin plot mainly because the axis in which the groups `X` and `Z` will appear, is already used for the "height" of the density. I did try to reach the same result by repeating all the calculations by groups but I'm stuck in the final step:

```
## Shaded grouped violin plot ##
# Calculate limits and median by group #
df.lim <- df %>% 
            group_by(X, Z) %>% 
            summarise(Y_min = min(Y),
                      Y_qnt = quantile(Y, 0.5),
                      Y_max = max(Y))

# Calculate density, truncate at limits and assign shade category by group #
df.dens <- df %>% 
            group_by(X, Z) %>% 
            do(data.frame(LOC  = density(.$Y)$x,
                          DENS = density(.$Y)$y)) %>%
            left_join(., df.lim, by = c("X", "Z")) %>% 
            filter(LOC >= Y_min, LOC <= Y_max) %>% 
            mutate(COL = ifelse(LOC > Y_qnt, "Empty", "Filled"))

# Find density values at limits by group #
df.lim.2 <- df.dens %>%
              group_by(X, Z) %>% 
              filter(LOC == min(LOC) | LOC == max(LOC))

# Produce shaded grouped violin plot #
df.dens %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = LOC, group = interaction(X, Z))) + 
    # The following two lines don't work when included #
    #geom_area(aes(y =  DENS, alpha = COL), fill = "red") +
    #geom_area(aes(y = -DENS, alpha = COL), fill = "red") +
    geom_path(aes(y =  DENS)) +
    geom_path(aes(y = -DENS)) +
    geom_segment(data = df.lim.2, aes(x = LOC, y = DENS, xend = LOC, yend = -DENS)) +
    coord_flip() + 
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c("Empty" = 0.1, "Filled" = 1))
```

Running the code above will produce the outline of the violin plots for each group, each one on top of the other. But once I try to include the `geom_area` lines, the code fails.

My gut feeling tells me that I would need to somehow produce the "shaded" violin plot as a new `geom` which can then be used under the general structure of `ggplot2` graphics but I have no idea how to do that, as my coding skills don't extend that far. Any help or pointers, either along my line of thought or in a different direction would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't think `geom_area()` is going to solve your problem when the violins are anywhere else than near 0. It would probably be better to replace it with `geom_polygon()`. The best guide I've found to creating your own geoms and such is here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea**

For the fun of it, I hacked a quick *half-violin geom*. It is basically a lot of copy & paste from `GeomViolin` and in order to make it run I had to access some of the internal `ggplot2` function, which are not exported via `:::` which means that this solution may not run in the future (if the `ggplot` team decides to change their *internal* functions).

However, this solution works and you can specify the alpha level of both the upper and the lower part. The `geom` assumes that you are providing just one quantile. The code is only superficially tested but it gives you an idea of how this can be done. As said it is in large part a simple copy & paste from `GeomViolin` where I added some code which finds out which values are below and above the quantile and splits the underlying `GeomPolygon` in 2 parts, as this function uses just a single alpha value. It works with `groups` and `coord_flip` likewise.

---

**Code**

```
library(grid)

GeomHalfViolin <- ggproto("GeomHalfViolin", GeomViolin,
  draw_group = function (self, data, ..., draw_quantiles = NULL, 
                         alpha_upper = .5, alpha_lower = 1) {
    data <- transform(data, xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin), 
        xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))
    newdata <- rbind(transform(data, x = xminv)[order(data$y), 
        ], transform(data, x = xmaxv)[order(data$y, decreasing = TRUE), 
        ])
    newdata <- rbind(newdata, newdata[1, ])
    if (length(draw_quantiles) > 0 & !scales::zero_range(range(data$y))) {
        stopifnot(all(draw_quantiles >= 0), all(draw_quantiles <= 
            1))
        stopifnot(length(draw_quantiles) <= 1)
        ## need to add ggplot::: to access ggplot2 internal functions here and there
        quantiles <- ggplot2:::create_quantile_segment_frame(data, draw_quantiles)
        ###------------------------------------------------
        ## find out where the quantile is supposed to be
        quantile_line <- unique(quantiles$y)
        ## which y values are below this quantile?
        ind <- newdata$y <= quantile_line
        ## set the alpha values accordingly
        newdata$alpha[!ind] <- alpha_upper
        newdata$alpha[ind] <- alpha_lower
        ###------------------------------------------------
        aesthetics <- data[rep(1, nrow(quantiles)), setdiff(names(data), 
            c("x", "y", "group")), drop = FALSE]
        aesthetics$alpha <- rep(1, nrow(quantiles))
        both <- cbind(quantiles, aesthetics)
        both <- both[!is.na(both$group), , drop = FALSE]
        quantile_grob <- if (nrow(both) == 0) {
            zeroGrob()
        }
        else {
            GeomPath$draw_panel(both, ...)
        }
        ###------------------------------------------------
        ## GeomPolygon uses a single alpha value by default
        ## Hence, split the violin in two parts
        ggplot2:::ggname("geom_half_violin",
                         grobTree(GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata[ind, ], ...),
                                  GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata[!ind, ], ...),
                                  quantile_grob))
        ###------------------------------------------------
    }
    else {
        ggplot2:::ggname("geom_half_violin", GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, 
            ...))
    }
  } 
)

geom_half_violin <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ydensity",
                             position = "dodge", ..., draw_quantiles = NULL,
                             alpha_upper = .5, alpha_lower = 1, 
                             trim = TRUE, scale = "area", 
                             na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
    layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomHalfViolin, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(trim = trim, scale = scale, draw_quantiles = draw_quantiles, 
                      alpha_lower = alpha_lower, alpha_upper = alpha_upper,
                      na.rm = na.rm, ...))

}


library(tidyverse)

# Create dummy data #
set.seed(321)
df <- data.frame(X = rep(c("X1", "X2"), each = 100), 
                 Y = rgamma(n = 200, shape = 2, rate = 2),
                 Z = rep(c("Za", "Zb"), rep = 100),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Grouped violin plot #
df %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = Z)) + 
    geom_half_violin(draw_quantiles = 0.5, alpha_upper = .1) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Za" = "red", "Zb" = "blue"))
# no groups
df %>% filter(Z == "Za") %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = X, y = Y)) + 
    geom_half_violin(draw_quantiles = 0.5, alpha_upper = .1, fill = "red") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Za" = "red", "Zb" = "blue")) + 
    coord_flip()
```

---

**Graphs**

[image: Grouped Half-Violin Plot]
[image: Flipped Half-Violin Plot]

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind! I made a minor edit as `alpha_lower` and `alpha_upper` were defined the other way round, but it seems to work perfectly. Once the edit is approved, I'll accept the answer. NIce work!

Comment: Really cool! Too bad it relies on non-exported functions. Perhaps you could add which version of `ggplot2` it works with, so people can replicate it in the future even if ggplot changes internally.

Comment: Though being internal functions, I do not think those functions will change any time soon. I guess one could easily drop `ggplot2:::ggname` ("just" adds a name to the grob), and the workhorse function `ggplot2:::create_quantile_segment` is also used by `geom_violin`. Looking at the source code of it, is relies mainly on basic R functions, so not too difficult to re-built (removing the `ggplot2` sugar). For the record this was done with `ggplot 3.2.0`.